# How to convert resources file extension to use in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

How to convert a .resources extension file to use in sql server 2008.I have a file with extension '.resources'. (MS ACCESS DB)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSIS tools or Import\Export Wizard on SQL Server.